# WebDriver does not accept js alert in Chrome

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm new at webdriver and I learnt how to handle JS alert things from different blogs. I could not find my problem solution. Actually when I am going to accept my js alert in Firefox the same code works fine, but once I changed my browser into Chrome it raises exception even I put to wait driver before and after it not work. What am I doing wrong?

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[xxxxxx]")).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());

Alert al = driver.switchTo().alert();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());

String Alert1 = al.getText();

al.accept();

System.out.println(Alert1);

Assert.assertEquals(Alert1, "xxxxxxx");
```

Comment: What exception do you see?

Comment: here is exception.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from unknown error: unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32000,"message":"Internal error: result is not an Object"}
  (Session info: chrome=47.0.2526.106)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.20.353145 (343b531d31eeb933ec778dbcf7081628a1396067),platform=Windows NT 10.0 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 78 milliseconds

Comment: Hi, try with Thread.sleep(3000); its works good in case of alerts in my scripts. any how, here you can also try with javascriptExecutor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i got who is culprit. 
Actually this alert executes in Iframe and main window and Iframe URLs are different with each other. Once I go on that page which URL and Iframe (alert) URL are same then chrome is not raising exception and same code works fine.

Answer (score 4):

You might solve the problem by changing the version of ChromeDriver to v2.18.

I encountered the same bug when I tried to deal with the alert appeared in the iframe. I finally change the the version of ChromeDriver to v2.18 and my test passed.

Probably this bug issue for ChromeDriver is related to your problem. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1224&colspec=ID%20Status%20Pri%20Owner%20Summary
This issue was found in ChromeDriver v2.19, v2.20, and v2.21.

Comment: This has been fixed in v.2.22 - see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1224#c18

Answer (score -1):

Put a small thread sleep before accepting the alert

```
    Thread.sleep(100);
    driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```